# Centos / vsFTPD / Nginx / php-fpm - Permission denied (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: centos, nginx, php-fpm, ftp

I have a clean Centos 6.4 (x64) minimal edition installed (fully updated).

Once the OS was setup, I followed this relatively simple guide to setup my FTP:
http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-to-configure-ftp-server-on-centos-6/

```
SELinux is disabled.
anonymous_enable=NO (vsFTPD Config)
chroot_local_user=YES (vsFTPD Config)
```

instead of creating a linux local user acc on /ftp/[username] (as per guide), I opted to use the standard location of /home/[username] where [username] was **server** (in my setup)

I tested my FTP Server and it is installed & running fine/. So I logged on to FTP and created a folder called "public_html" and then created a index.php file inside it with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` code in it. ( So full path is : /home/server/public_html/index.php )

I then installed nginx & php-fpm and proceeded to create the following configuration files for each in this order.

**/etc/php-fpm.d/server.conf** (php-fpm pool for my local nix acc: server):

```
[server]

listen = '/var/run/php-fcgi-server.sock'
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = server
group = server

pm = static
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 200

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/server-php-errors.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = on
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev-minecraft.local.conf** (nginx vHost):

```
upstream serverbackend {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-server.sock;
}

server {
    listen *:80 default;
    server_name dev-minecraft.local;

    root /home/server/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   serverbackend;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now, if I visit the site no my browser : http://dev-minecraft.local/ I get the following error: **500 Internal Server Error**

And I see the following errors in my **/var/log/nginx/error.log** file:

```
2013/07/22 12:58:07 [crit] 2039#0: *1 stat() "/home/server/public_html/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.15, server: dev-minecraft.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.54"
2013/07/22 12:58:07 [crit] 2039#0: *1 stat() "/home/server/public_html/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.15, server: dev-minecraft.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.54"
2013/07/22 12:58:07 [crit] 2039#0: *1 stat() "/home/server/public_html/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.15, server: dev-minecraft.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.54"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?
One thing I noticed in WinSCP (after i login via FTP), the file owner/group is set to a numeric identifier (500) instead of the account username "server". Is this the reason why nginx/php-fpm is unable to access the site files? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using proftpd and not vsftpd? Because chroot_local_user is an option of vsftpd

Comment: apologies, I was looking at proftpd earlier and went with vsftpd, but the name stuck in my head. Yes, it is vsFTPD.

Comment: I've fixed the `500 Internal Server Error` error by editing the nginx vhost config file and replacing "last" with "break" -> http://pastebin.com/uExiUZ6Y fixed config (however, that permission denied for `stat()` still exists on nginx error log

Comment: # ls -lad /home/server/ /home/server/public_html/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions of `/home/server` deny access to anyone but its owner. That is what `drwx------` means.

To resolve the issue, allow other users to descend into the directory.

```
chmod a+x /home/server
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a permission problem. The php-fpm user and the nginx user must have read access to the files in your directory. Also your nginx configuration is a bit problematic. Please try the following:

```
client_max_body_size    10M;
index index.html        index.php;

upstream serverbackend {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-server.sock;
}

server {
    server_name   dev-minecraft.local;
    root          /home/server/public_html;
    expires       30d;

    location / {

        location ~ \.php$ {
            expires         off;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass    serverbackend;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would love to know what was wrong with my nginx config. I've been using something similar for allot of my projects and it's been fine. What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Always specify options in the most outer scope and change them on a server basis if you need to. E.g. `index` is most certainly the same for all your servers, so specify it in the `http` context (outermost allowed place for it). You can always check the documentation to know which is the outermost place for an option. Keep things as easy as possible. Nest regular expression locations in other locations (create a tree). Do not allow PHP execution on folders where user uploads are allowed, instead of complicated rewrites and file system checks. Your config is not(!) wrong, just not optimal.